# Translating conditional statements in string format to actual logic

Tags: javascript, conditional-statements

I have a good knowledge of real time graphics programming and web development, and I've started a project that requires me to take a user-created conditional string and actually use those conditions in code. This is an entirely new kind of programming problem for me.

I've tried a few experiments using loops and slicing up the conditional string...but I feel like I am missing some kind of technique that would make this more efficient and straightforward. I have a feeling regular expressions may be useful here, but perhaps not.

Here is an example string:

```
"IF#VAR#>=2AND$VAR2$==1OR@VAR3@<=3"
```

The values for those actual variables will come from an array of objects. Also, the different marker symbols around the variables denote different object arrays where the actual value can be found (variable name is an index).

I have complete control over how the conditional string is formatted (adding symbols around IF/ELSE/ELSEIF AND/OR 
well as special symbols around the different operands) so my options are fairly open. How would you approach such a programming problem?

Answer (score 0):

The problem you're facing is called [parsing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsing#Programming_languages) and there are numerous solutions to it. First, you can write your own "interpreter" for your mini-language, including lexer (which splits the string into tokens), parser (which builds a tree structure from a stream of tokens) and executor, which walks the tree and computes the final value. Or you can use a parser generator like [PEG](http://pegjs.majda.cz/) and have the whole thing built for you automatically - you just provide the rules of your language. Finally, you can utilize javascript built-in parser/evaluator `eval`. This is by far the simplest option, but eval only understands javascript syntax - so you'll have to translate your language to javascript before eval'ing it. And since eval can run arbitrary code, it's not for use in untrusted environments.

Here's an example on how to use eval with your sample input:

```
expr = "#VAR#>=2AND$VAR2$==1OR@VAR3@<=3"

vars = {
    "#": {"VAR":5},
    "$": {"VAR2":1},
    "@": {"VAR3":7}
}

expr = expr.replace(/([#@$])(\w+)(\1)/g, function($0, $1, $2) {
    return "vars['" + $1 + "']." + $2;
}).replace(/OR/g, "||").replace(/AND/g, "&&")

result = eval(expr) // returns true
```